Incorrect Word Selection and Cursor Behavior in RTL TextField with Special Characters
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/155153#issue-2524461141
Steps to Reproduce:

Open Flutter's documentation on handling changes to a text field.
Paste the code from my code sample into the page.
Enter the following text into the TextField: שלום לכולם, בדיקה ניסיון.
Press Enter and paste the same text again on the next line.
Select any word from the first line by double-clicking it and check the cursor position while navigating with the left and right arrow keys.
Go to the end of the first line and add a special character, such as ,.
Attempt to select any word by double-clicking and observe the cursor position.

Additional Notes:

The problem occurs not only with a comma but with any special character at the end of the line (e.g., ., \, /, ?, !, etc.).
The issue seems to affect all lines except the last line. For example, if you create 5 lines with the text שלום לכולם, בדיקה ניסיון,, the selection on the last line will be correct, but the 4 preceding lines will have incorrect behavior.

Expected results

Words should be selected from start to end without any issues when double-clicking.
The cursor should move between letters without any problems.
When pressing the delete or backspace key, the correct letter should be removed.

Actual results

After step 7, word selection is broken when double-clicking.
The cursor does not accurately move between letters.
Deleting or backspacing does not remove the correct letter.
Special characters at the end of a line cause incorrect selection and cursor behavior on all lines except the last one.

Code sample
Code sample
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Retrieve Text Input',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

// Define a custom Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyCustomForm> createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the Form.
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a text controller and use it to retrieve the current value
  // of the TextField.
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Start listening to changes.
    // myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
    myController.addListener(() {
      if (myController != null) {
        if (myController.selection ==
            TextSelection.fromPosition(
                TextPosition(offset: myController.text.length - 1))) {
          myController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
            TextPosition(
              offset: myController.text.length,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _printLatestValue() {
    final text = myController.text;
    print('Second text field: $text (${text.characters.length})');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              minLines: 1,
              controller: myController,
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              maxLines: 2,
              onChanged: (text) {
                print('First text field: $text (${text.characters.length})');
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              minLines: 1,
              maxLines: 2,
              controller: myController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Screenshots or Video

Screenshots / Video demonstration
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/c498e553-e9fb-4a36-88b0-004861bdd516
Logs
Logs

The issue is reproducible in Flutter's documentation on handling changes to a text field.

Flutter Doctor output
Doctor output

The issue is reproducible in Flutter's documentation on handling changes to a text field.

Different font families, including monospace, do not significantly help with this issue.
